# How to get started with PHPUnit at the command line?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a **MacBook Pro**, installed **PEAR**, installed **PHPUnit**, so at the command line I can type `phpunit` and I get the **usage** help.

Now I want to **get a test going** so that I can build from there.

I have a file named `index.php` with this content:

```
<?php

require_once '?????';


class Product {

    protected $id;

    public function __construct($id) 
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function get_id()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}

class ProductTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    function testBasis()
    {
        $instance = new Product(1);

        $this->assertInstanceOf('Product',$instance);
        $this->assert($instance->get_id(), 1);
    }
}
```

At the command line, I want to go to the directory in which the file is located and type something like:

```
phpunit ?????
```

**What are the next steps so that I am able to test the above class with PHPUnit from the command line?**

Comment: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html

Comment: yes, that is the documentation I am reading (chapter 4) where chapter 3 shows how to install pear/phpunit which I did, and chapter 4 assumes that the rest in installed, but when I type "phpunit productTest" it can't find "./ProductTest.php" and when I type "phpunit index.php" it says, "callt o undefined method ProductTest::assert()", I need to get a basic example working so I can use that documentation.

Comment: Becouse assert is not defined , have a look at chapter 21 to see all available functions ( eg. looks like you're trying to use assert when you realy need is assertEquals() , allso assertInstanceOf() needs to be replaced with isInstanceOf() )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If you installed phpunit proprely you don't need the include line .
2. `class ProductTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`
3. Save the file `ProductTest.php`
4. At the command line browse using "cd" to the directory where you saved ProductTest.php
5. If you installed phpunit proprely you should be able to enter `phpunit --verbose ProductTest.php`

Your ProductTest.php file will have to look like this :

```
<?php

class Product {

    protected $id;

    public function __construct($id) 
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function get_id()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}

class ProductTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    function testBasis()
    {
        $instance = new Product(1);

        $this->isInstanceOf('Product',$instance);
        $this->assertEquals($instance->get_id(), 1);
    }
}

?>
```

At the command line running `phpunit --verbose ProductTest` , will output :

```
PHPUnit 3.4.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.

ProductTest
.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 6.50Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
dorin@ubuntu:/var/www$ phpunit --verbose ProductTest
PHPUnit 3.4.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.

ProductTest
.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 6.50Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

Comment: ok, I did that and it tells me `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method ProductTest::assert()` which is telling me that it is not finding `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` or what could be the reason?

Comment: copy my exact code , save it in a file called ProductTest.php and you'll see all tests will pass .

Comment: yes, it works now, `assert` and the file name were the problems, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the phpunit version from 3.4 to 3.6 using [these instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/55055/how-to-install-an-updated-version-of-pear-phpunit-on-ubuntu) and it solved my assertInstanceOf missing function problem. if someone came on this thread for looking same problem, should think to upgrade to latest version of phpunint test