# PHPUNIT - Show Blank message

Tags: php, phpunit

I am trying to write unit test using PHP Unit. Here is code.

```
<?php
require_once 'E:/bin/phpunit.phar';
//use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

final class FirstUnitTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function test1() {
        $this->assertEquals(5+5,10);
    }
}

$obj = new FirstUnitTest();
$obj->test1();
?>
```

Geting Following answer only

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

What is wrong with this code. I was accepting answer should be **OK**.

I am run this file though Browser not from the command line.

Comment: Have a look at something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594998/how-to-get-started-with-phpunit-at-the-command-line which shows how you would normally run unit tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not how you use PHPUnit. Have a look at https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-9.html for how to get started.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to run PHP Unit test case

```
<?php
require_once 'E:/bin/phpunit.phar';
//use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

final class FirstUnitTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function test1() {
        $this->assertEquals(5+5,10);
    }
}
?>
```

For window Machine

```
C:\Users\username>path\to\php path\to\phpunit.phar --verbose FirstUnitTest
```

Or you can use by set path environment variable

```
C:\Users\username>php phpunit --verbose FirstUnitTest
```